# Export TypeScript Class to Browser Window and Node.js without bundler (browserify or webpack)

Tags: typescript

I have the following example class in TypeScript:

```
export default class Greeter {
    greeting: string;

    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }

    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

That uses the following tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "umd",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "files" :[
        "example.ts"
    ]
}
```

Using the transpiler, it generates the following JavaScript:

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
        var v = factory(require, exports);
        if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var Greeter = (function () {
        function Greeter(message) {
            this.greeting = message;
        }
        Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
            return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
        };
        return Greeter;
    }());
    exports.Greeter = Greeter;
});
```

I have tested a lot of things with different modules (umd,commonjs), however i'm unable to make that the class works in Node.js and the Browser at the same time with the same code (using require that works with Angular,React and in the Window object of the browser). I'm trying to achieve something like:

```
// With Node.js, Angular, React etc

let Greeter = require("Greeter");
let instanceGreeter = new Greeter("My Name");
instanceGreeter.greet();

// And that works in the browser too with the same codebase

var instanceGreeter = new Greeter("My Browser Name");
instanceGreeter.greet();
```

Is this possible by following any standard or do i have to export it with my own code (not using the module option)?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, i couldn't find anything that matches my needs without a trick. I ended up creating 2 `tsconfig.json` files (one for every type e.g module and window) that will generate 2 JavaScripts files. One is meant to be used in the browser without using any kind of bundler like Webpack, Browserify etc and the second one works (or should at least) work with import, require etc.

The disadvantage with this approach is that you will need to remove the export default keyword in your class if you want to compile to the version of the window e.g :

```
// If willing to export to window remove `export default` e.g 
// class Greeter {
// instead of 
// export default class Greeter {
export default class Greeter {
    greeting: string;

    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }

    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

As there can only be a tsconfig.json file on every directory, i created the build-instructions folder with 2 folders inside namely commonjs and window:

```
build-instructions
├───commonjs
|   └── tsconfig.json
├───window
    └── tsconfig.json
```

The `commonjs/tsconfig.json` (that works for modules as require, import etc) looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "outDir":"../../build"
    },
    "files" :[
        "../yourtypescriptfile.ts"
    ]
}
```

And the window (that works in the browser) looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "none",
        "target": "es5",
        "outFile":"../../build/yourlibrary.window.js"
    },
    "files" :[
        "../yourtypescriptfile.ts"
    ]
}
```

When executing the npm command in the root folder of the project (to transpile TypeScript) with:

```
# For CommonJS
tsc --p ./path-to-folder/commonjs

# For Window
tsc --p ./path-to-folder/window
```

Both of them will create a JavaScript file compatible for every type, for the browser with a result like:

```
var Greeter = (function () {
    function Greeter(message) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    };
    return Greeter;
}());
```

And for the module (according to the module you use like umd, commonjs or amd):

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    // If willing to export to window remove `export default` e.g 
    // class Greeter {
    // instead of 
    // export default class Greeter {
    var Greeter = (function () {
        function Greeter(message) {
            this.greeting = message;
        }
        Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
            return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
        };
        return Greeter;
    }());
    exports.default = Greeter;
});
```